# Instalacion apk

Tags: android

He creado varias apk en Android studio que he instalado en varios moviles, pero ahora desde hace un tiempo, no se me instala en ningun movil ni siquiera en los que antes si, y no he cambiadom nada de la app.
Intenta instalarlo pero me dice el mismo movil : "No he podido instalarlo".

Si lo realizo a traves de android studio y enchufando por usb el movil al ordenador, si lo instala.

¿Que puede suceder?

Comment: Estás instalando la misma aplicación con el mismo versionCode?. Estás comprobando que sean versiones diferentes?

Comment: Si, y ademas en la mayoria de los moviles es la primera vez que la instalo. No va a ser una aztualizacion de google que no deja instalarlas?

Comment: Hola Fernando, agrega más información, cual es tu Manifest.xml?, esta firmado o no tu .apk?, que realiza esta aplicación? , etc, revisa [ask]